# Дата изменения Google SpreedSheets

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

суть такая. Есть колонка D, и при изменении значения в этой колонке, в строке этого значения в колонке H должна вставляться дата его изменения. Как это реализовать и куда вставлять код в гугл таблицах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала почитайте оф. документацию [здесь](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) либо используйте код как в примере.

```
function onEdit(e){
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  let row = e.range.getRow();
  let column = e.range.getColumn();

  if (column == 4) {
    sheet.getRange(row, 8).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```